# running Javascript on button click

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to Javascript so I'm not sure if my code is working as I'm not sure how to test or run it. What I want my code to do is display the JSON created from gathering all the checked boxes. I haven't added a `console.log` anywhere because I'm not sure where it would be appropriate. I feel as though I have all the pieces but I am not sure how to put everything together.

The expected output should be:

```
{
  "testpages" : [...data...],
  "configs" : [...data...]
}
```

My code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function grabSelected() {
    var configs = [];
    var testPages = [];
    var selectedConfigs = document.getElementByClassName('.testpages').value;
    var selectedTestPages = document.getElementByClassName('.configs').value;
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedConfigs.length; i++) {
      if (selectedConfigs[i].checked) {
        configs.push(selectedConfigs[i])
      }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedTestPages.length; i++) {
      if (selectedTestPages[i].checked) {
        testPages.push(selectedTestPages[i])
      }
    }
    var jsonString = {"testpages" : testpages, "configs" : configs};
    var testJson = JSON.stringify(jsonString);
  }
  </script>
  <body class="wrap">
    <form action="POST" >
      <div class="testpages" id="left_col">
        <input id="tp1" type="checkbox" value="1">Test Page 1<br>
        ...
        ...
        <input id="tp30" type="checkbox" value="30">Test Page 30<br>
      </div>
      <div class="configs" id="right_col">
        <input id="config_0" type="checkbox" value="Windows XP internet explorer 8">Windows XP 
        ...
        ...
        <input id="config_59" type="checkbox" value="OS X 10.9 Safari 7">OS X 10.9 Safari 7<br>
      </div>
    </form>
    <input id="" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="grabSelected();" />
  </body>
<html>
```

Comment: Close your `<script>`

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek good catch. I think i might have deleted too much when I was shortening my code

Comment: So what is working, is the function running? You can `console.log` at the start of the function to see if it's running.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek i dont think my function is working as console.log doesnt output anything

Comment: Does the page reload? It's in a form, you may want to add `return false` on the end.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek as soon as I click submit all the checks in the check boxes go away so I am assuming yes

Comment: Add `return false;` at the end to prevent the page reload (it prevents the form from submitting). Then the `console.log` should show up.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek will occurs =/ when I click submit, i get redirected to the same URL but with a ? appended ot the end

Answer (score 1):

Some of the (trivial) mistakes found in your original code:

- Used getElementByClassName instead of getElementsByClassName
- Used testpages instead of testPages in jsonString formation
- Used the classnames testpages and configs for parent div instead of
  input elements.

Here's the one you can use:

```
    <html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function grabSelected() {
    var configs = [];
    var testPages = [];
    var selectedConfigs = document.getElementsByClassName('testpages');
    var selectedTestPages = document.getElementsByClassName('configs');
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedConfigs.length; i++) {
      if (selectedConfigs[i].checked) {
        configs.push(selectedConfigs[i].value)
      }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedTestPages.length; i++) {
      if (selectedTestPages[i].checked) {
        testPages.push(selectedTestPages[i].value)
      }
    }
    var jsonString = {"testpages" : testPages, "configs" : configs};
    var testJson = JSON.stringify(jsonString);
  }
  </script>
  <body class="wrap">
    <form action="POST" >
      <div id="left_col">
        <input class="testpages" id="tp1" type="checkbox" value="1">Test Page 1<br>
        <input class="testpages" id="tp30" type="checkbox" value="30">Test Page 30<br>
      </div>
      <div id="right_col">
        <input class="configs" id="config_0" type="checkbox" value="Windows XP internet explorer 8">Windows XP 

        <input class="configs" id="config_59" type="checkbox" value="OS X 10.9 Safari 7">OS X 10.9 Safari 7<br>
      </div>
    </form>
    <input id="" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="grabSelected();" />
  </body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that you're trying to return the value of the class instead of checking to see if is checked. Instead of getElementByClassName().value, try getElementByClassName(id).getElementsByTag('input'). This will return an array that you can loop through and return the values for.

Apologies for answer formatting, typed from SO app.